# Нужно написать программу, вычисляющую окончательную сумму банковского вклада

Tags: python, циклы

Суть в том, что есть `n` - сумма, к примеру `1.000.000` и процентная годовая ставка. Хотел написать код который: переменная `numb1 = 1.000.000*16/100` (показывает итоговые годовые начисления)
Дальше надо узнать месячные начисления: `numb2 = numb1/12`
Это всё у меня получилось. Проблема у меня возникла на моменте, когда я захотел подсчитать итоговую сумму с реинвестированием. То есть берём месячные выплаты и заново закидываем к общей сумме и так каждый месяц. Как это сделать, дайте ответ пожалуйста!) В своё оправдание скажу, что я уже больше 2 лет не занимаюсь этим. Ушел из программирования в другую сферу :)

Comment: Покажите весь ваш код

Comment: numb1 = 10000000
pers = 16
numb2 = numb1*pers/100
numb3 = numb2/12
numb4 = numb1+numb3
numb5 = numb4*pers/100/12+numb4
numb6 = numb5*pers/100/12+numb5


print(numb6)

Comment: numb1 = 10000000
pers = 16
numb2 = numb1*pers/100
numb3 = numb2/12
numb4 = numb1+numb3
numb5 = numb4*pers/100/12+numb4
numb6 = numb5*pers/100/12+numb5
print(numb6)

Comment: То есть, вместо numb5, numb6 и последующих numb7, 8, 9...

Comment: Надо сделать цикл, чтобы numb4 = numb1+numb3 и потом по кругу из numb2 = numb4*pers/100 numb3 = numb2/12 numb5 = numb4+numb3

Comment: Понятно. Мне пока некогда - работа, может кто другой не поленится...

Comment: Лучше объясню на примере, есть вклад на сумму 1.000.000 руб. За год я получаю 16% от этой инвестиции. То есть 1.160.000 руб. В месяц это составит около 13.333 руб. А я хочу посчитать, что если я буду инвестировать обратно каждый месяц начисленные проценты? То есть у меня есть 1.000.000 руб., ежемесячно я получаю по 13.333 руб. Значит если в первый месяц я добавлю эти деньги к первоначальной сумме - будет 1.013.333 руб, а значит 16% от этой суммы уже будет 162.133 руб. То есть в следующем месяце я получу уже 13.511 руб, которые я также реинвестирую. Вот и хочу посчитать, что будет в конце года.

Comment: Вообще-то я тоже уже давно не занимаюсь инвестициями. Но помню, что месячнай процент не равен годовому проценту/12. Т.е. неправильный изначальный посыл и ваши выкладки - ошибочны. Гууглите тему "сложные проценты". Информации много. С правильными формулами.

Comment: @passant Ну почему же. При вкладе с капитализацией процентов - вроде бы именно так считается. Другое дело, что на самом деле капитализация даёт очень небольшой прирост, если посчитать. У меня вон получилось примерно 1% к 16% прибавился. А если взять реальные наши 5% или сколько там сейчас по вкладам, то вообще смех один будет от капитализации. Если в мой расчёт из ответа подставить 5%, с капитализацией выйдет 5.11% ))))

Comment: @CrazyElf Увы нет. 0.013333% доходности в месяц не дает доходность 16% в год при СЛОЖНОМ проценте. Реальный годовой доход будет 17.227% Аналогично, если у вас фиксирована годовая доходность в 16%, то месячная доходность будет менше 1.3333% Есть формаула, искать сейчас нет возможности.

Comment: @passant Так вы про обратную задачу говорите - посчитать какой процент нужно накидывать каждый месяц, чтобы получить заданный итоговый процент прибыли за год с учётом "капитализации"?

Comment: @CrazyElf - если я правильно понял ТС, то он считает, что если за год он получил 16%, за месяц это бы ему дало 1.3333 процента. Это не так. И если бы он их реинвестировал, то получил бы более 16%.  Вот я ему и показал, если фиксирован годовой процент -  то за месяц он не добавляет 1.333% к его вкладу. Вот посчитал, при вкладе на 16% годовых в месяц вклад увеличивается на 1.2445%

Comment: Интересная беседа пошла) Нет, на самом деле дело обстоит так: Я открыл в иностранном банке, вклад в их валюте. То есть там годовая процентная ставка - 16% Они разделили эти 16% на 12 частей и выплачивают ежемесячно.

Comment: То есть ровно так, как я посчитал. 16% от суммы вклада, разделенные на 12.

Answer (score 1):

Ну примерно так:

```
initial = deposit = 1_000_000
percent = 16/100
print(f'начальный депозит: {initial}, годовой процент: {percent*100}')

for month in range(12):
    income = deposit * percent / 12
    deposit += income
    print(f'месяц: {month+1}, доход: {income}, вклад: {deposit}')

year_percent = (deposit - initial) / initial
print(f'годовой процент с учётом капитализации составил: {year_percent*100}')
```

Вывод:

```
начальный депозит: 1000000, годовой процент: 16.0
месяц: 1, доход: 13333.333333333334, вклад: 1013333.3333333334
месяц: 2, доход: 13511.111111111111, вклад: 1026844.4444444445
месяц: 3, доход: 13691.259259259261, вклад: 1040535.7037037037
месяц: 4, доход: 13873.80938271605, вклад: 1054409.5130864198
месяц: 5, доход: 14058.793507818931, вклад: 1068468.3065942386
месяц: 6, доход: 14246.244087923182, вклад: 1082714.5506821617
месяц: 7, доход: 14436.194009095489, вклад: 1097150.7446912571
месяц: 8, доход: 14628.67659588343, вклад: 1111779.4212871406
месяц: 9, доход: 14823.725617161874, вклад: 1126603.1469043025
месяц: 10, доход: 15021.375292057368, вклад: 1141624.52219636
месяц: 11, доход: 15221.660295951466, вклад: 1156846.1824923113
месяц: 12, доход: 15424.615766564151, вклад: 1172270.7982588755
годовой процент с учётом капитализации составил: 17.22707982588755
```

P.S. Если подставить более реальные 5% годовых в этот расчёт, то на выходе будет:

```
годовой процент с учётом капитализации составил: 5.116189788173302
```

Таким образом, в реальности "капитализация процентов" практически ничего не даёт, это просто маркетинговый ход банков. Более высокий процент по вкладам обычно выгоднее, чем "капитализация" на более низкий процент.

Comment: Спасибо большое!)

Comment: Большое спасибо всем! И благодарю за совет по поводу сложных процентов)

Answer (score 1):

Как посчитать помесячно - уже ответили, а я отвечу, как можно посчитать сразу итоговую сумму: [tio.run](https://tio.run/##XY3NCoMwEITvPsUcFfZQ@wcV7LFP0JvkkECkERslGtCnT7Pbngp72Jmd@Xbe19fkTylptOhqwpFwJlwIV9nz3AgHcdhURREXy9lniBb9FLDBeeh8YOFIpPXxbYNebamrpgBcj1zrnGIBGAYM0h5o/y9wekPbYleSznK0vjQV7qi/AGAOzq/lRjDVzxEas0wjzwaVvzz0uNiUPg)

```
s = 1000000 # вклад
p = .16     # под 16%
t = 12      # на 12 месяцев

print(s * (1 + p/12)**t)
```

```
1172270.798258877
```

Впрочем, реально банки считают не 1/12 за месяц, а долю числа дней в месяце к году, а ещё оно каждый месяц округляется. Так что результат не совсем сойдётся.